# Hover background (scale up) with text in front not getting scale up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transforms

When user hover on the image, the image is getting bigger. But I also have some information to show in front of the image.

This is what I've done so far:

```css
.home-about-link {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.home-about {
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.home-about:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  /* IE 9 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.1, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.1, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
  /* IE8 */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.1, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.1, SizingMethod='auto expand');
  /* IE6 and 7 */
}

h2 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-about-link">
  <div class="home-about">
    <h2>ABOUT US</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

What the code do is when user hover on the image, the information (ABOUT US text) is also getting bigger. What I tried to get is the information font is stay same as before, only the background scale up. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you don't want to scale the `h2` along with the background.

One way is to reverse scale the `h2` with a scale factor 1/1.1 = 0.909

```
.home-about:hover h2{
  transform: scale(0.909);
}
```

Let me know your feedback on this. Cheers!

```css
.home-about-link {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.home-about {
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.home-about:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  /* IE 9 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.1, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.1, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
  /* IE8 */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.1, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.1, SizingMethod='auto expand');
  /* IE6 and 7 */
}
h2 {
  color: #fff;
}
.home-about:hover h2 {
  transform: scale(0.909);
}
```

```html
<div class="home-about-link">
  <div class="home-about">
    <h2>ABOUT US</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this result are you  are expecting check the output in jsbin

just reduce the value of the

```
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1)
```

to

```
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
```

[Jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/hixiru/edit?html,css,output)

***css***

```
.home-about-link{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.home-about{
    background: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.home-about:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);<!----check the changes-------->
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1); /* IE 9 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.1, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.1, SizingMethod='auto expand')"; /* IE8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.1, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.1, SizingMethod='auto expand'); /* IE6 and 7 */ 
}

h2{
  color: #fff;
 }
```

***html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="home-about-link">
      <div class="home-about">
        <h2>ABOUT US</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```